# SQL Query Display records only when value is missing

Tags: sql

I am having an issue, I am new to SQL query work, but I have a query that runs and display employees and all their addresses history, but I have found that staff have been missing checking off the indicator for if the employee has mailing address. The addresses are stored in a table that has a reference to the employee id. How would I display results for a specific employee if no "2" value for mailing is found. The address table contains previous addresses and billing address flags, "1" and "3"?

In the addelement table

```
type_add_id|type_add_desc 
1          |Billing 
2          |Mailing 
3          |Previous
```

Query

```
SELECT
  addelement.type_add_desc
  ,address.street
  ,employee.name

FROM
  address
  INNER JOIN addelement
    ON address.type_add_id = addelement.type_add_id
  INNER JOIN employee
    ON address.refid = employee.refid

order by employee.name
```

Comment: this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/. we need more information, db schema, what query have you using, what is "1", "2" and "3"

Comment: sorry about that... I updated it

Comment: You use [**LEFT JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) instead of `INNER JOIN` this will return rows even if not found anyone to match in the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a list of employees that do not have a mailing address.  Note that we start with all employees, outer join to the addresses, but constrain to not only match the employee, but also to be of the desired type of address.  The `WHERE` clause then removes records from the resulting recordset where there is a value.

```
SELECT
  employee.name
FROM
  employee
  LEFT OUTER JOIN address ON address.refid = employee.refid AND address.type_add_id = 2
WHERE
  address.type_add_id IS NULL
```

Change the hardcoded integer in the `JOIN` to search out each of the desired types of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e30116/1 and tell me what you think.

If the "2" is not there, it will simply give you the result of the other addresses.

Comment: Even when sqlFiddle is great, sometimes doesnt work, so you should always include your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll make sense of this query easier than the one with a left join. It an also be confusing to understand why the filtering condition on the join must be with the join and not in the `where` clause. It'll be good for you to understand that eventually though if you continue learning SQL.

```
select *
from employee e
where not exists (
    select 1
    from address a
    where a.refid = e.refid and a.type_add_id = 2
)
```

Many people seem to object to subqueries because their platforms don't optimize them well or because they see it as a crutch in using SQL. I suppose in a sense I am offering it here as an equivalent solution to help ramp up your understanding but either way I see nothing wrong with taking advantage of `in` and `not in` as a natural way of expression the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should return your employee #100 with all the addresses stored, even if employee has not address (any type).

```
select e.name, ad.type_add_desc, a.street
from employee e
left outer join address a on
e.refid = a.refid
left outer join addelement ad on
a.type_add_id = ad.type_add_id
where e.refid = 100
order by e.name;
```

To return rows that haven't a row relationship in other table you should use OUTER JOIN.